# Swift 4 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) not triggering when i dissmiss viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a *viewControllerA* that is presented programmatically without segues in storyboard, like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IdStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idcontroller") as! BController
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then from *viewControllerA* I go to *viewControllerB*, using a storyboard segue.

When I dismmiss *viewControllerB*  `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`, `viewDidAppear` is not triggered in *viewControllerA*.

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear): _"If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller after the presented controller is dismissed."_

Comment: When i present with seague videDidApear triggers every time when i dismiss B. So my question is: if i have videcontroller A and B. If i dismiss B can i triger event in A?

Comment: Is the viewController file of both "A" and "B" is in the same storyBoard

Comment: nop 2 separated storyboards...

Comment: jvrmed answered it correctly, maibe my question is not so well formatted ... but the ideea is to triger a func in A when i dismiss B. Where A is firs viewcontroller and B second. In android onresume solves this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to trigger an event in *viewControllerA* when dismissing *viewControllerB* I suggest **creating a delegate** method to link both.

On your *viewControllerA* include the following:

```
protocol TriggerEventDelegate {
    func eventToBeTriggered();
}
```

Then make your *viewControllerA* conform to that protocol:

```
extension AController: TriggerEventDelegate {
    func eventToBeTriggered() {
         // Implement whatever you want to trigger here
    }
}
```

**On your *viewControllerB***, create a *delegate* reference:

```
class BController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: TriggerEventDelegate? 
}
```

**Implement the triggering** whenever you are dismissing *viewControllerB*:

```
func dismiss() {
    delegate?.eventToBeTriggered()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Last but not least**, when moving from *viewControllerA* to *viewControllerB* set your `delegate` with *viewControllerA*:

```
func pushFromAToB() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IdStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:     "idcontroller") as! BController
    controller.delegate = self
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Your event will now be triggered properly without having to rely on `viewDidAppear`

Comment: u are the best .... the only modification i have done is : protocol TriggerEventDelegate : class{
    func eventToBeTriggered();
}

Comment: nice, I am glad it helped!